# Simulate chromatic filter on RGB image

Tags: filters, image-processing, color

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/44338/19249) but I believe it is slightly different, which is why I am posting a new question.

Given an image in RGB format, I want to know if it is possible to simulate (at least approximately) how the image would look like if a chromatic filter had been used on the lens when the picture was taken.

I understood from the answer in the question I linked above that this is impossible, but I was wondering if a procedure like this one would make sense:

1. Assume that every pixel in the image is a superposition of pure colors, which have specific wavelengths.
2. Find the superposition that would lead to each color (for example, the RGB color `[255 255 255]` would be a superposition of all the wavelengths in the visible spectrum).
3. Remove the wavelengths that we wish to filter out.
4. The resulting image is the approximated filtered one.

I am in doubt with the 2nd step, because I don't know if there is a way to determine which pure colors would form each possible RGB value. If that were possible to achieve, then I believe the procedure I have described above would make sense.

- Is it possible to find which wavelengths should be in superposition to achieve every RGB value?
- If that is possible, wouldn't then my approach be a sensible way to get an approximate simulation of what a chromatic filter would have worked like if it had been used when taking the picture?

Comment: A physical scene does not contain only pure color (single wavelength), but in general a complex mixture of wavelengths. A rgb camera sensor is somewhat similar to a 3-band filterbank. Except there is significant overlap and irregularity. I believe that you lack the information to do a «virtual» band stop filter of rgb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is based on [Fast RGB to Spectrum Conversion for Reflectances](http://scottburns.us/fast-rgb-to-spectrum-conversion-for-reflectances/). As there are only 3 degrees of freedom (DOF) in an RGB data file and there are effectively infinite DOF in a continuous spectrum this mapping will not be unique.

The output spectrum is given by:
$$\rho(\lambda) = r\rho_R(\lambda) + g\rho_G(\lambda) + b\rho_B(\lambda)$$
where $r$, $g$, and $b$ are an RGB triplet normalized to the range 0 to 1, and $\rho_R(\lambda)$, $\rho_G(\lambda)$, and $\rho_B(\lambda)$ are given below.

```
rho_R
0.021592459, 0.020293111, 0.021807906, 0.023803297, 0.025208132,
0.025414957, 0.024621282, 0.020973705, 0.015752802, 0.01116804,
0.008578277, 0.006581877, 0.005171723, 0.004545205, 0.00414512,
0.004343112, 0.005238155, 0.007251939, 0.012543656, 0.028067132,
0.091342277, 0.484081092, 0.870378324, 0.939513128, 0.960926994,
0.968623763, 0.971263883, 0.972285819, 0.971898742, 0.972691859,
0.971734812, 0.972344540, 0.971503390, 0.970857997, 0.970553866, 0.969671404

rho_G
0.010542406, 0.010878976, 0.011063512, 0.010736566, 0.011681813,
0.012434719, 0.014986907, 0.020100392, 0.030356263, 0.063388962,
0.173423837, 0.568321142, 0.827791998, 0.916560468, 0.952002841,
0.964096452, 0.970590861, 0.972502542, 0.969148203, 0.955344651,
0.892637233, 0.500364100, 0.116236717, 0.047951391, 0.027873526, 
0.020057963, 0.017382174, 0.015429109, 0.015438080, 0.014546826,
0.015197773, 0.014285896, 0.015069123, 0.015506263, 0.015545797, 0.016302839

rho_B
0.967865135, 0.968827912, 0.967128582, 0.965460137, 0.963110055,
0.962150324, 0.960391811, 0.958925903, 0.953890935, 0.925442998,
0.817997886, 0.425096960, 0.167036273, 0.078894327, 0.043852038,
0.031560435, 0.024170984, 0.020245519, 0.018308140, 0.016588218, 
0.01602049, 0.0155548080, 0.013384959, 0.012535491, 0.011199484,
0.011318274, 0.011353953, 0.012285073, 0.012663188, 0.012761325,
0.013067426, 0.013369566, 0.013427487, 0.013635740, 0.013893597, 0.014025757
```

In these tables the first entry is for 380 nm and there is a 10 nm step between entires.

Now that you are in the spectral domain you can perform your filtering.

To return to the RGB domain I've usually done a conversion from spectrum, to [XYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CIE_1931_color_space&oldid=1003199947#Computing_XYZ_from_spectral_data), and then to RGB.  I've included my code below.  For more background you can visit the Wikipedia [CIE 1931 color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CIE_1931_color_space&oldid=1003199947) page.

**Spectrum to XYZ**

```
double piecewise_gaussian(double x, double alpha, double mu, double sigma1,
                          double sigma2) {
    double t = (x - mu) / (x < mu ? sigma1 : sigma2);

    return alpha * std::exp(-(t * t) / 2);
}

color_xyz wavelength_to_xyz(double lambda) {
    color_xyz xyz;

    xyz.c[0] = piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 1.056, 599.8, 37.9, 31.0)
        + piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 0.362, 442.0, 16.0, 26.7) 
        + piecewise_gaussian(lambda, -0.065, 501.1, 20.4, 26.2);

    xyz.c[1] = piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 0.821, 568.8, 46.9, 40.5) 
        + piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 0.286, 530.9, 16.3, 31.1);

    xyz.c[2] = piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 1.217, 437.0, 11.8, 36.0) 
        + piecewise_gaussian(lambda, 0.681, 459.0, 26.0, 13.8);

    return xyz;
}
```

**XYZ to RBG**

```
color_rgb xyz_to_rgb(color_xyz xyz) {
    color_rgb rgb;

    rgb.c[0] = 0.4184700 * xyz.c[0] - 0.1586600 * xyz.c[1] - 0.082835 * xyz.c[2];
    rgb.c[1] = -0.0911690 * xyz.c[0] + 0.2524300 * xyz.c[1] + 0.015708 * xyz.c[2];
    rgb.c[2] = 0.0009209 * xyz.c[0] - 0.0025498 * xyz.c[1] + 0.178600 * xyz.c[2];

    return rgb;
}
```

The complete loop from RBG -> spectrum -> to RBG above is unnormalized.  For the application I had used it for this was unimportant.  My recommended strategy for a reasonable normalization is as follows:

1. Start with an RGB white value (1, 1, 1)
2. Convert to the equivalent spectrum
3. Convert back to RGB space
4. Compute the "brightness" of the new RGB value, the RGB value may no longer be a triple of the same value for all three components (that's why I used the quotation marks)
5. Use the inverse of the computed brightness for the new value as a constant scale factor for all of your transformations

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried your approach, but I am having a problem. I tried it with just a white pixel, without filtering anything (I didn't change the spectrum), and then I tried to reconstruct the original white pixel but I get a dark one. Is there something wrong with my code or is this a possible effect of metarism? I also tried with other colors, and in all of them it seems that the bright colors are darker in some sense (i.e. the white turns to some kind of gray, the magenta to a dark pink). Does this make sense?

Comment: @Tendero For my application I wasn't worried about normalization so the complete loop is likely un-normalized.  I will updated my response to have a brief discussion on normalization.

Comment: The problems is that normalizing makes other RGB values (non-white ones) to go out of scale. I mean, dividing by a number smaller than 1 makes other RGB values to be greater than 1, and thus all the other colors are lost. Does this make sense or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Tendero, that's part of the problem with mapping a spectrum to an RGB triple, you may be running into a color gamut problem where not all of the specta are representable under the model used.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can find something else to correct these aspects, but your response definitely helped me out to get it started. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tendero glad I could help.  There are a lot of different takes on this if you poke around in some of the computer graphics areas.  Lots of tradeoffs in going between 3 and infinite dimensions.